# Flink DataSet program runs several jobs

Tags: apache-flink

I have the following code in Apache Flink. 
When I execute it, some parts of my code are run twice.
Could some one let me know why is that happening?

```
DataSet input1 = ...
DataSet input2 = ...

List mappedInput1 = input1
    .map(...)
    .collect();

DataSet data = input1
    .union(input1.filter(...))
    .mapPartition(...);

data = data.union(data2).distinct();

data.flatMap(new MapFunc1(data.collect()));

data
    .flatMap(new MapFunc2(input2.collect()))
    .groupBy(0)
    .sum(1)
    .print();
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code example to the relevant parts and improve the formatting (proper indention, line wrapping to avoid scrolling, ...). It is hard to figure out what you are doing there.

Comment: Here is related code! I updated one line code in the main method and added the richFlatMapFunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `collect()` and `print()` statement eagerly triggers an execution and fetches the result to the client code. Each such call tracks back the whole program to the data sources.

Your code contains three `collect()` and one `print()` statement. Hence, four individual programs are submitted and executed. Instead of using `collect()`, you should have a look at [broadcast variables](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/programming_guide.html#broadcast-variables). Broadcast variables distribute a DataSet to each parallel instance of an operator. The computation and distribution happens in the same program and is not routed over the client program. Instead the data is directly exchanged between the workers running the operators.

Comment: dPairs.flatMap(new TC(dPairs.collect())).setParallelism(1); As you can see in this Line of code, I would like to use dPairs generated in previous steps in two places. would that work to use a broad cast variable here? Another question, Would that be accessible in all of the nodes?

Comment: If you share `dPairs` with a broadcast variable to `flatMap(new TC())`, it is available to all parallel instances of `TC` (which has parallelism 1 in your case). Flink will detect that the double use of `dPairs` creates a branching and merging data flow and automatically take care that the program is executed without a deadlock.

Comment: Using the broadcast variable as in example,  I receive Null pointer exception while accessing the broadcasted variable!